# DataGridCheckboxColumn with SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, checkbox, dataset

I´ve got the following DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="8" Height="583" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dgAufgaben" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1344" AlternatingRowBackground="#E6DBDBDB" RowHeight="55">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="sseas"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

which I fill in this way:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        aufrep.GetAufgaben(ds, loginid);
        dgAufgaben.DataContext = ds;
        dgAufgaben.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

So the data, that I receive out of my database are in the `DataSet`, the columns are autogenerated. The problem is, that I don´t know how to set the CheckboxColumn to the value of a column of my `DataSet`. (One column cointains 0 and 1 values)

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do know with AutoGenerate = true it will probably create that column a second time.  In SQL bool is bit (0,1).  You just bind to that column.

```
        DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
        Header="New?" 
        Width="40"
        Binding="{Binding IsNew}"
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I just added the checkboxcolumn for testing. In my database, the column with the value 0/1 is a int. Can I initialize a bool and bind it to these? If yes, what else do I have to do that it works?

Comment: "In SQL bool is bit (0,1)"   So change it from Int to Bit in SQL.

Comment: ok. And then? How can I get the value into IsNew(in your example)?

Comment: Use the name of the column in the DataTable.   You might be able to use [0].